# Insert form value into mysql database with pdo

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Hi I changed my mysql querys into pdo. Now the problem is that I havent any experience with pdo. I edit it how I thought but nothing works. No errors are showing. Can anyone find the mistake? Thanks for reading.

```
    <?php
     session_start();

    if(isset($_POST["submit"])){

    $hostname='localhost';
    $username='root';
    $password='';


function generateRandomString($length = 8) {
    $characters = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
    $charactersLength = strlen($characters);
    $randomString = '';
    for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
        $randomString .= $characters[rand(0, $charactersLength - 1)];
    }
    return $randomString;
}
$randomString = generateRandomString();


         if ($_POST['password'] != $_POST['password_again']) {
            $message['error'] = 'Die eingegebenen Passwörter stimmen nicht überein.';
        } else {
            unset($_POST['password_again']);
            $salt = ''; 
            for ($i = 0; $i < 22; $i++) { 
                $salt .= substr('./ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789', mt_rand(0, 63), 1); 
            }
            $_POST['password'] = crypt(
                $_POST['password'],
                '$2a$10$' . $salt
            );

            try {
            $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=loginsystem",$username,$password);

            $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION); // <== add this line
            $sql = "INSERT INTO user2 (username, password, email, firstname, lastname, phone, town, street, zip, country, code)
            VALUES ('".$_POST["username"]."','".$_POST["password"]."','".$_POST["email"]."','".$_POST["firstname"]."','".$_POST["lastname"]."','".$_POST["phone"]."','".$_POST["town"]."','".$_POST["street"]."','".$_POST["zip"]."','".$_POST["country"]."','".$_POST[$randomString]."')";
            if ($dbh->query($sql)) {
            echo "New Record Inserted Successfully";
            }
            else{
            echo "Data not successfully Inserted.";
            }

            $dbh = null;
            }
        catch(PDOException $e)
                    {
            echo $e->getMessage();
            }

            $new = rowCount();
            if ($new == 1) {
                $message['success'] = 'Neuer Benutzer (' . htmlspecialchars($_POST['f']['username']) . ') wurde angelegt, <a href="login.php">weiter zur Anmeldung</a>.';
                header('Location: http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '//activation.php');

                // $empfaenger = $_POST['f']['email'];
                // $betreff = "Registration";
                // $from = "From: Webmaster <webmaster@somediashout.de>";
                // $text = "Thank you for your registration. Your code is : " + $randomString;

                // mail($empfaenger, $betreff, $text, $from);



                    $_SESSION = array(
                        'login' => true,
                        'user'  => array(
                            'username'  => $row['username']
                        )
                    );

            } else {

            }

        }
    } 
?>
```

Comment: *taking a deep breath...*, okay, the point with PDO is to have an up to date api that allows you to easily use prepared statements to avoid sql injection, you're not preparing anything, you're simply concatenating a string that can easily be injected. Check existing solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

brabus85,

The first answer checks if any error is remaining OR not. Please replace below code on first answer.

This code contains total solution of your problem.

```
<?php
session_start();

if(isset($_POST["submit"])){

        $hostname='localhost';
        $username='root';
        $password='';


        function generateRandomString($length = 8) {
                $characters = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
                $charactersLength = strlen($characters);
                $randomString = '';
                for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
                        $randomString .= $characters[rand(0, $charactersLength - 1)];
                }
                return $randomString;
        }
        $randomString = generateRandomString();


        if ($_POST['password'] != $_POST['password_again']) {
                $message['error'] = 'Die eingegebenen Passwörter stimmen nicht überein.';
        } 
        else {
                unset($_POST['password_again']);
                $salt = ''; 
                for ($i = 0; $i < 22; $i++) { 
                        $salt .= substr('./ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789', mt_rand(0, 63), 1); 
                }
                $_POST['password'] = crypt(
                                                                $_POST['password'],
                                                                '$2a$10$' . $salt
                                                                );
                $new = 0;
                try {
                        $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=loginsystem",$username,$password);

                        $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION); // <== add this line
                        $sql = "INSERT INTO user2 (username, password, email, firstname, lastname, phone, town, street, zip, country, code)
                        VALUES ('".$_POST["username"]."','".$_POST["password"]."','".$_POST["email"]."','".$_POST["firstname"]."','".$_POST["lastname"]."','".$_POST["phone"]."','".$_POST["town"]."','".$_POST["street"]."','".$_POST["zip"]."','".$_POST["country"]."','".$randomString."')";

                        if ($dbh->query($sql)) {
                                echo "New Record Inserted Successfully";
                        }
                        else{
                                echo "Data not successfully Inserted.";
                        }
                        $new = $dbh->lastInsertId();
                        $dbh = null;
                }
                catch(PDOException $e)
                {
                        echo $e->getMessage();
                }


                if ($new > 0) {
                        $message['success'] = 'Neuer Benutzer (' . htmlspecialchars($_POST['f']['username']) . ') wurde angelegt, <a href="login.php">weiter zur Anmeldung</a>.';
                        header('Location: http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '//activation.php');

                        // $empfaenger = $_POST['f']['email'];
                        // $betreff = "Registration";
                        // $from = "From: Webmaster <webmaster@somediashout.de>";
                        // $text = "Thank you for your registration. Your code is : " + $randomString;

                        // mail($empfaenger, $betreff, $text, $from);



                        $_SESSION = array(
                                'login' => true,
                                'user'  => array(
                                        'username'  => $row['username']
                                 ));
                } else {

                }
        }
}
?>
```

Let me know if you face any query/concern regarding this.

Thanks!

Comment: Many thanks for your attention, but I get an error: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'submit' (T_STRING), expecting ']' in C:\xampp\htdocs\socialad\registerpdo9.php on line 4

Comment: and if I make two of the " on line 4 away, then came: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'mysql' (T_STRING) in C:\xampp\htdocs\socialad\registerpdo9.php on line 38

Comment: It works, thank you buddy!! :) And good luck with your enterprise :)

Comment: Glad to know that our inputs worked flawlessly. Feel free to contact us for any further problems you encounter. :)

Answer (score 1):

brabus85,

I replaced code `$new = rowCount()` with `$new = $dbh->rowCount()`. Also cut this code and paste at before `$dbh = null` line, I have to initialize $new with 0 so write it before `try{}` statement.

Please use below code and let me know what you see.

```
<?php
session_start();
// Report all errors
error_reporting(E_ALL);

if(isset($_POST["submit"])){

        $hostname='localhost';
        $username='root';
        $password='';


        function generateRandomString($length = 8) {
                $characters = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
                $charactersLength = strlen($characters);
                $randomString = '';
                for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
                        $randomString .= $characters[rand(0, $charactersLength - 1)];
                }
                return $randomString;
        }
        $randomString = generateRandomString();


        if ($_POST['password'] != $_POST['password_again']) {
                $message['error'] = 'Die eingegebenen Passwörter stimmen nicht überein.';
        } 
        else {
                unset($_POST['password_again']);
                $salt = ''; 
                for ($i = 0; $i < 22; $i++) { 
                        $salt .= substr('./ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789', mt_rand(0, 63), 1); 
                }
                $_POST['password'] = crypt(
                                                                $_POST['password'],
                                                                '$2a$10$' . $salt
                                                                );
                $new = 0;
                try {
                        $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=loginsystem",$username,$password);

                        $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION); // <== add this line
                        $sql = "INSERT INTO user2 (username, password, email, firstname, lastname, phone, town, street, zip, country, code)
                        VALUES ('".$_POST["username"]."','".$_POST["password"]."','".$_POST["email"]."','".$_POST["firstname"]."','".$_POST["lastname"]."','".$_POST["phone"]."','".$_POST["town"]."','".$_POST["street"]."','".$_POST["zip"]."','".$_POST["country"]."','".$_POST[$randomString]."')";
                        if ($dbh->query($sql)) {
                                echo "New Record Inserted Successfully";
                        }
                        else{
                                echo "Data not successfully Inserted.";
                        }
                        $new = $dbh->rowCount();
                        $dbh = null;
                }
                catch(PDOException $e)
                {
                        echo $e->getMessage();
                }


                if ($new == 1) {
                        $message['success'] = 'Neuer Benutzer (' . htmlspecialchars($_POST['f']['username']) . ') wurde angelegt, <a href="login.php">weiter zur Anmeldung</a>.';
                        //header('Location: http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '//activation.php');

                        // $empfaenger = $_POST['f']['email'];
                        // $betreff = "Registration";
                        // $from = "From: Webmaster <webmaster@somediashout.de>";
                        // $text = "Thank you for your registration. Your code is : " + $randomString;

                        // mail($empfaenger, $betreff, $text, $from);



                        $_SESSION = array(
                                'login' => true,
                                'user'  => array(
                                        'username'  => $row['username']
                                 ));
                } else {

                }
        }
}

print('<pre> Message :: ');
print_r($message);
print('</pre>');

print('<pre> POST values from submitted form :: ');
print_r($_POST);
print('</pre>');

print('<pre> ACTIVE SESSION :: ');
print_r($_SESSION);
print('</pre>');

?>
```

Once check wording which is in array format:

1. Message
2. POST values from submitted form
3. ACTIVE SESSION

Hope you understand very well and let me know further query from this solution.

Thanks!

Comment: Notice: Undefined index: Xr8KyyXM in C:\xampp\htdocs\socialad\registerpdo9.php on line 44
New Record Inserted Successfully
Fatal error: Call to undefined method PDO::rowCount() in C:\xampp\htdocs\socialad\registerpdo9.php on line 51

Comment: Thank you, the variables are in my database but the redirection to activation.php wont work, any hints? :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead of `$dbh->query()`

```
$sth=$dbh->prepare($sql);
$sth->execute();
```